# login system with mySql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am using ASP.NET C# with mySql database. What is the best way for implementation of login system like Membership and Role. Membership and Role dont work with mySql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The membership and role systems work quite fine as long as you use the proper providers. You can use [the 'official' providers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html) or even write your own, if you want.

Comment: Now I'd try with this tutorial, tnx